# Using CMake with Qt5 and Qt Plugins

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, qmake

I'd like to avoid using `qmake` and `.pro` files. The problem is that I cannot get `cmake` to work nicely with `Qt Plugins`. I've included the code below showing the interface, plugin, loader that work correctly for the given `.pro` file but I cannot figure out how to transfer this functionality to `cmake`.

### Plugin Interface

Pure virtual interface, known by the loader.

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

class HelloPluginInterface
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() const = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE( HelloPluginInterface, "com.harbrick.Qt.HelloPluginInterface")
```

### Plugin

Plugin that becomes a `.so` to be loaded by the loader.

```
#include <QtPlugin>
#include "helloplugin_global.h"

class HelloPlugin : public QObject, public HelloPluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA( IID "com.harbrick.Qt.HelloPluginInterface" )
    Q_INTERFACES( HelloPluginInterface )

public:
    void DoSomething() const;
};
```

### Plugin Loader

```
void MainWindow::LoadPlugin( const QString& pathToLibrary )
{
    QPluginLoader loader( pathToLibrary );
    QObject* instance = loader.instance();

    if( instance )
    {
        HelloPluginInterface *plugin = qobject_cast< HelloPluginInterface* >( instance );
        if(plugin)
        {
            //do stuff
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Not a plugin: " << Filename << " = " << loader.errorString();
        }
    }
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

**Can't get to work**

```
project( HelloPlugin )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.11 )

set( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

include_directories( 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
)

set( INCLUDE
    cmakeplugin.h
    cmakeplugininterface.h
)

set( SOURCES
    cmakeplugin.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${INCLUDE} ${SOURCES} ${SRC_LIST})

add_library( cmakePlugin SHARED cmakeplugin.cpp )
```

### QMake .pro

**Works**

```
QT       += widgets

TARGET = HelloPlugin
TEMPLATE = lib

SOURCES += helloplugin.cpp

HEADERS += helloplugin.h \
    helloplugin_global.h

CONFIG += plugin debug

INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: "Can't get to work" which errors do you get?

Comment: "Not a library" on the load. I've figured it out, will post a solution.

Comment: @DaveyLaser Seems to be a very complex solution when it is taking you years to post it. ;)

Comment: Wow @Nobody, haha! Thanks for pointing that out, I'll post a solution sometime in the next couple of years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qt generates meta code for plugins, add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

Here's a complete working example:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(test-plugin)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(COMPILE_OPTIONS -std=c++11)

add_library(test-plugin SHARED test-plugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test-plugin PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
target_compile_options(test-plugin PRIVATE ${COMPILE_OPTIONS})

add_executable(test-plugin-exec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test-plugin-exec PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
target_compile_options(test-plugin-exec PRIVATE ${COMPILE_OPTIONS})
```

**test-plugin-interface.hpp**

```
#ifndef TEST_PLUGIN_INTERFACE
#define TEST_PLUGIN_INTERFACE
#include <QtPlugin>

class TestPluginInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~TestPluginInterface() {}
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
};

#define TestPluginInterface_iid "whatever.you.want.TestPluginInterface"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(TestPluginInterface, TestPluginInterface_iid)
#endif // TEST_PLUGIN_INTERFACE
```

**test-plugin.hpp**

```
#ifndef TEST_PLUGIN_HPP
#define TEST_PLUGIN_HPP
#include <QObject>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include "test-plugin-interface.hpp"

class TestPlugin : public QObject, public TestPluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID TestPluginInterface_iid)
    Q_INTERFACES(TestPluginInterface)

public:
    ~TestPlugin() override {}
    void doSomething() const override;
};
#endif // TEST_PLUGIN_HPP
```

**test-plugin.cpp**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "test-plugin.hpp"

void TestPlugin::doSomething() const
{
    qDebug()<< "hot dog!";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include "test-plugin.hpp"

constexpr auto ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PLUGIN = 
    "/path/to/build/libtest-plugin.so";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(QLibrary::isLibrary(ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PLUGIN));
    QPluginLoader loader(ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PLUGIN);
    if (auto instance = loader.instance()) {
        if (auto plugin = qobject_cast< TestPluginInterface* >(instance)){
            plugin->doSomething();
        }
        else {
            qDebug()<< "qobject_cast<> returned nullptr";
        }
    }
    else {
      qDebug()<< loader.errorString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had all the code but was missing the MOC option. Checking the difference with [nm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) revealed two added functions: `qt_plugin_instance` and `qt_plugin_query_metadata`

Comment: Does the interface need to be the same class or can it be just two classes that look the same? I'm asking because I'm thinking about having the plugin in a separate project then the one using the plugin so they cannot share the same interface file.

Comment: Yes, this works, the interface just need to look similar and have the same iid.