# Qt object's staticMetaObject address different in executable than linked dll

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, linker, dllexport

I'm having an issue with the address of a QObject's `staticMetaObject` being different when read from my main executable's code vs. from a dll loaded using a `QPluginLoader`. The class in question belongs to the loaded DLL. The DLL is also linked at build time for different reasons. This issue is causing a `qobject_cast` to fail, because the template argument I give has a different `staticMetaObject` than what the `metaObject()` method returns, and the meta object system compares addresses of meta objects to check inheritance.

What makes it confusing is that this only seems to happen on Windows, and further still it only happens if I use CMake instead of QMake.

It must be my build instructions, but I don't know enough about library linkage to know. I would have chalked this up to it being the fact that a static variable inside a DLL loaded at runtime will of course have a different address, but I don't understand why this doesn't happen with the QMake version of my project.

It feels like a symbol visibility/export issue.

I have tried setting `WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` or just adding `-Wl,--export-all-symbols` to all targets, but nothing changed. The library is linked using `target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE dll)`, where `dll` is the library in question.

Comment: what toolchain, -Wl... suggests some version of mingw? Could you create an MRE with both cmake and qmake and possibly dump the compilation commands? From the top of my head, do compiler switches like fPIC or fPIE (provided it's mingw) ring any bells?

Comment: "dll loaded using a QPluginLoader" - This means that "dll" is a **dynamically loaded** library. But `target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE dll)` means that you link with "dll" at **link time**. Generally, these are incompatible actions for a single library.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318274/3440745) provides an example of building QT plugin with CMake.

Comment: @alagner I'll try to replicate it in a sample project and attach the output when I can.

Tsyvarev, I did feel that linking and opening it at runtime are... strange choices, but I do not have control over that, unfortunately. I'd discuss with the team who owns the code to change it, but it does work with our qmake build system, so they would not see a reason to change.

Comment: The build system is indeed MinGW 10, 64 bit, g++ 11.2.0. We do not compile with fPIC or fPIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was user error. In order to run straight from the build directory, Qt Creator offers to add build library paths to your run environment, but for CMake that doesn't work well, so I had to add CMake instructions to copy the DLL to the executable's folder. The plugin loader was referencing the DLL inside a `lib` subfolder in the build directory, but the DLL opened as part of the executable starting was the one in the same directory.

Two identical DLLs, but different locations. My guess is since the one in the executable directory is already open by the executable, opening it again with the plugin loader reuses the addresses of things, but if opened with a different path, it's different address space.

I didn't see our plugin loader searching outside the executable directory, so I fixed that and it works now.

Comment: Seems like a similar problem, just not QT related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147729/dll-file-loaded-twice-with-dll-redirection-through-manifest

Comment: This was just an error in our codebase, though. You have to tell the QPluginLoader the file path of the library to load, and in this case our code was ignoring the library in the executable directory and searching through other directories.